# Android/Eclipse - How to get class member dropdowns, etc

Tags: android, eclipse

I've only been using Eclipse since installing it to use for Android development. I was previously using Galileo, but the other day downloaded Helios (the "Classic" config as recommended on the Android site).

My project builds and everything is OK except that I no longer get the code-completion dropdowns when typing. In other words, when I type "this.", I do not see the popup list of all the members and methods. Eclipse does know everything about the classes, as hovering the cursor over anything pops up the expected info.

Am I missing a preference setting or something else? The preferences are pretty complex and I'm not sure what the feature that's lacking is called in Eclipse nomenclature.

Doug Gordon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

java > Editor > typing
there should be an option in there.
does ctrl+shift (or is it alt+shift) work?
I generally turn off that option anyways as I feel it just slows me down.

Comment: Well, Ctrl-Shift (or maybe it was Alt-Shift) resulted in my getting a dialog that said something about some Content Assist contents being disabled and recommended restoring defaults. I clicked that link and it started working again. Maybe it was something that happened when upgrading the workspace settings.